# The toggle menu does not working when reclicking

Tags: javascript, menu, toggle, responsive

I have a responsive menu with this theme : https://splash.stylemixthemes.com/basketball/ in wordpress.
In this theme the menu works very well.
On my website, when I click on an item the submenu is displaying. 
But when I reclick the sub-menu remains when it should be folded back. 
Perhaps It is  a conflict problem. But I don't know how I can fix it and where I can see where is the problem (is there a way to desactivate script js one by one for example ?)
Thanks

```js
    function menu () {
      if ($(this).parent("li").hasClass("menu-item-has-children") && !$(this).parent("li").hasClass("active")) {

    $(this).closest("li").siblings().find("ul").slideUp();
    $(this).closest("li").siblings().find("li").toggleClass("active");

    $(this).next("ul").slideDown();
    $(this).parent("li").addClass("active").siblings().toggleClass("active");

    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="stm-mobile-menu-unit" style="display: none;">
       <div class="inner">
        <div class="stm-top clearfix">
         <div class="stm-switcher pull-left">
               </div>
         <div class="stm-top-right">
          <div class="clearfix">
           <div class="stm-top-search">
                   </div>
           <div class="stm-top-socials">
                   </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="stm-mobile-menu-list heading-font">
         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1754 active"><a href="#"><span>BIG PAGE</span></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu" style="">
           <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1755 stm_col_width_default stm_mega_cols_inside_default active"><a href="https://www.mydomain.fr/page-1/"><span>Page 1</span></a></li>
           <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1757 stm_col_width_default stm_mega_cols_inside_default active"><a href="https://www.mydomain.fr/page-2/"><span>Page 2</span></a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-2197 active"><a href="#"><span>BIG PAGE 2</span></a>
         <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1968 stm_col_width_default stm_mega_cols_inside_default"><a href="https://www.mydomain.fr/page-3/"><span>Page 3</span></a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2203 stm_col_width_default stm_mega_cols_inside_default"><a href="https://www.mydomain.fr/page-4/"><span>Page 4</span></a></li>
         </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2279 active"><a href="https://www.mydomain.fr/galerie-photos/"><span>BIG PAGE 3</span></a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
  html body.header_4 ul.header-menu li.active:after {
    content: '\f107' !important; }
  html body.header_4 ul.header-menu li.menu-item-has-children {
    padding-right: 40px; }
    html body.header_4 ul.header-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after {
      content: "\f105";
      display: block;
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      font-size: 21px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 10px;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
              transform: translateY(-50%); }
    html body.header_4 ul.header-menu li.menu-item-has-children a:after {
      display: none !important; }
    html body.header_4 ul.header-menu li.menu-item-has-children.active > ul.sub-menu {
      visibility: visible !important;
      opacity: 1 !important; }
      html body.header_4 ul.header-menu li.menu-item-has-children.active > ul.sub-menu > li {
        overflow: hidden; }
        html body.header_4 ul.header-menu li.menu-item-has-children.active > ul.sub-menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
          height: 100% !important;
          visibility: visible !important;
          opacity: 1 !important; } }
```

Comment: Please post the minimal code to show a running example of your issue. We really can't help unless we see the relevant HTML and the CSS as well.

Comment: So difficult to show CSS because the file is too long ... i don't know how can I do ...

Comment: Clearly, you've got to fix your syntax error(s) and give us the relevant CSS before we can help.

Comment: I use a wordpress website and it is difficult to give a short css with just the menu elements. I try to give the relevant CSS.

Comment: If you click the "Run code snippet" button below your code, you will see that you have an anonymous function declaration, which is invalid in this case.

Comment: Yes I had a name in my function but it still display " function statement requires a name"

Comment: No, you have a parameter name, not a function name.

Comment: tss yes indeed !

Comment: Impossible to give all the css... I give the url theme and i can give my url in private if possible..

Comment: You're asking a question about toggling the `active` class. That's all the CSS we need.